# How to use optional attribute for assumed shape arrays

Tags: fortran, option-type

I encountered the following situation while using the Fortran **optional attribute** 
for an assumed shape array and trying to figure out the best (in terms of performance) solution. 
I would be very glad if someone could give me a good hint. 
Please note, that I am interested in every performance gain I can get, since my arrays are large and the number of loops and their cycles are even larger.

I have the situation that a calculation is done either using the optional argument or in case it is not present it uses another array at its place.

```
  subroutine compute(tmat,av,av2)
  implicit none
  complex,intent(out)           :: tmat(:)   
  complex,intent(in)             :: av(:)      
  complex,intent(in),optional    :: av2(:)     

  if(present(av2)) then
      tmat = av *av2
  else
      tmat = av *av
  end if

  end subroutine compute_transition_matrices_bosonic
```

In this simple example, the above solution would be fine. Nevertheless, my true code is much more complicated.
This means that the inner block of the routine may be very large (hundreds of lines) and most important contain many nested loops.
One could imagine it like the following:

```
  if(present(av2)) then
      tmat = "function"(av,av2)
  else
      tmat = "function"(av,av)
  end if
```

where "function" stands for a lot of operations and loops (therefore the ""). The point is that these are the same operations for both cases of
the if statement such that I need to write the code twice. The other solution would be to check if `av2` is present at the position of usage in the 
code which would create some overhead since this check would be done very (very) often.

I was wondering if there is a more clever solution to such a problem. First, one might think of using a temp variable

```
  complex,                :: phi_tmp(:)

  if(present(av2)) then
      phi_tmp = av2
  else
      phi_tmp = av
  end if

  tmat = "function"(av,phi_tmp)
```

which is done often when using optional arguments. But this would COPY the data, which is in my case a really huge array.
Therefore, I was thinking of using a pointer

```
  complex,intent(in),target             :: av(:)      
  complex,intent(in),optional,target    :: av2(:)   
  complex,pointer                :: phi_tmp(:)

  if(present(av2)) then
      phi_tmp => av2
  else
      phi_tmp => av
  end if

  tmat = "function"(av,phi_tmp)
```

But this requires the `TARGET` attribute for `av` and `av2`. Here I am not sure whether this would cause performance drop since the compiler 
can not assume any more that `av` and `av2` have NO aliases in its optimization procedure, even though here both have the `INTENT(IN)` attribute 
such that no aliasing problem can occur. Furthermore, what does it mean if the argument which is in the input when calling the routine does
not have the `TARGET` attribute? (This compiles and works!)

Does anyone has some experience with these issues?
Is there a "standard" solution? (I couldn't find one)
What ultimately is the best solution?

Comment: Is the "assumed shape" aspect significant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I suggest is your last solution with pointers, there is no problem if the actual argument have no target attribute, the pointer will become undefined at the exit of the routine, but as long as you don't pass it back to the calling procedure that wouldn't matter.

You can use an other subroutine (an internal one, for example) to perform the actual computation, that routine wouldn't know that its argument are aliased and, basically, if they both have the `intent(in)` attribute, that will be fine. So no performance will be lost.

```
subroutine compute(tmat, av, av2)
  implicit none
  complex, intent(out)                  :: tmat(:)
  complex,intent(in),target             :: av(:)      
  complex,intent(in),optional,target    :: av2(:)   
  complex,pointer                :: phi_tmp(:)

  if(present(av2)) then
     phi_tmp => av2
  else
     phi_tmp => av
  end if

  call compute_internal(tmat, av, phi_tmp)

contains
  subroutine compute_internal(tmat, av, av2)
    complex,intent(out)       :: tmat(:)
    complex,intent(in)        :: av(:)      
    complex,intent(in)        :: av2(:)

    .....

  end subroutine
end subroutine
```

Comment: Really nice idea. Thank you for this suggestion. I never thought of having an internal routine in a routine (wasn't even sure if this works). I appreciate your version because it allows me on the one hand to keep my structure as it is (using the optional argument) and on the other hand seems to avoid possible performance loss. 
Did I get you correct that since the calculation is performed in the internal routine which does not have the target attribute, the optimization procedure of the compiler is not hindered ?

Comment: As far as I know the optimization procedure shouldn't be hindered. But nobody knows what a compiler will do.

Answer (score 4):

One approach would be to use distinct subroutines for the present and not-present cases.

```
subroutine compute1(tmat,av)
  implicit none
  complex,intent(out)           :: tmat(:)   
  complex,intent(in)            :: av(:)      

  call compute2(tmat, av, av)  ! Ensure there is an explicit interface for compute2 here
end subroutine

subroutine compute2(tmat,av,av2)
  implicit none
  complex,intent(out)           :: tmat(:)   
  complex,intent(in)            :: av(:)      
  complex,intent(in)            :: av2(:)     

  tmat = "function"(av,av2)
end subroutine
```

where neither has an optional argument.

This can be added to with making `compute` a generic for both of these.

Naturally, this won't work in all cases, but here with the `intent(in)` attribute on `av` and `av2` in `compute2` we don't have to worry about aliasing.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply and nice suggestion. Your way is very clean in a way that it **avoids** all of the above complications. Also the idea of a generic would lead to a clear and simple calling of the routine. The only drawback (which is by no means on the performance) would be the increase of the number of routines by a factor of three (I have this case more often in my code)

Comment: There is a lot of extra stuff here, yes (not helped by how bulky the specifications are).  However, it may be plausible to auto-generate a lot of the wrapper and generic parts, and even with submodules keep all of that out of the way.  [Not that it would be easy, necessarily...]